# Does my CPU support hardware virtualization?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, linux-kvm

I have an ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine installed with virtual box, and I've also installed KVM on it, from a MacBook pro with an intel i5 processor.
I'm trying to instantiate a virtual machine on my ubuntu VM (yes, a virtual machine inside a virtual machine) with OpenNebula, and the VM fails to launch. I can successfully load the kvm module, but it doesn't load kvm_intel:

[image]

And this is the content of /proc/cpuinfo:

[image]

But the strange thing is that I am able to run virt-manager and to create a virtual machine!! 
So maybe the problem is that the machine is 32-bit while my physical processor is 64 bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VirtualBox doesn't support hardware assisted VM's inside another VM.
(It's a known issue with VirtualBox.)

You can also tell from the cpuinfo readout: The VMX flag is not present.

Comment: Why was I able to create and execute a VM with virt-manager?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri those functions (running virt-manager and creating a vm) do not require virtualization support on the cpu.